# Return result in PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, but before modify specific column with function

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I was wondering is it possible to modify result before returning it.

```
public function getUserData(){
        $db = initDB();
        $getUserData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = :customer_id");
        $getUserData->bindParam(":customer_id", $_SESSION['customer_id']);
        $getUserData->execute();
        $userData = $getUserData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);            
        return $userData;
}
```

One of the columns content is encoded with `htmlspecialchars`. I just need to change that column before returning it.

I was already doing it like this, but I was wondering is there better way.

```
public function getUserData(){
        $db = initDB();
        $getUserData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = :customer_id");
        $getUserData->bindParam(":customer_id", $_SESSION['customer_id']);
        $getUserData->execute();
        $person = array();
        while($userData = $getUserData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              /* Rest of the columns without decoding */                  
              $person['content'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($userData['content']);
        }
        return $person;
}
```

Comment: This is simple and works without unnecessary actions, there is no reason to change this code. Looping over results to change a column is pretty common. Nothing weird here.

Comment: @Kaddath I agree. Is there way to add rest of the columns without typing them all separately? Like $person[$userData[''key]] = $userData['value'];

Comment: yes, just copy the whole row in `$person` first, and change only what needs to: `$person = $userData; $person['content'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($person['content']);` (edit or `$person[] = $userData` if you want to add as a new line, but this needs to change directly $userData before, or keep the index of last added row)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaddath pointed out. This was all alright.

All I need to change is:

```
$person = $getUserData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$person['content'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($person['content']);
return $person;
```

First to fetch, then modify then return. I was probably thinking it way too hard.